# \resizebox shifts tikzpicture up when in a subfloat environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, boxes, scaling

Why when I try to re-scale a `tikz` figure using `\resizebox` the baseline is shifted up (regardless of how small the scale factor is), and two horizontal floats are not aligned properly.

[image: not aligned]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}%
\subfloat[]{%
\fbox{
\resizebox{0.5\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node {a};%
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%end resize
}%fbox
}&%end subfloat
\subfloat[]{%
\begin{tabular}{c|cccc}%
  & 0 & 1 & \dots & n\\\hline
a & & & &\\
b & & & &\\
c & & & &\\
\dots & & & &\\
d & & & &\\
\end{tabular}%
}%end subfloat
\end{tabular}%
\caption{Why resizebox shifts the baseline up?}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you want to avoid the spurious space after `\fbox{` by adding `%` there as well. Note that with the `adjustbox` package you can simply write `\adjustbox{width=0.5\linewidth,fbox}{..}` or `\begin{adjustbox}{width=0.5\linewidth,fbox} .. \end{adjustbox}` and easily add more modifiers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is not the baseline of the `\resizebox` but the baseline of the tabular which is on its center by default. So changing the baseline of the tabular with `[b]` solves this issue:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}%
\subfloat[]{%
\fbox{
\resizebox{0.5\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node {a};%
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%end resize
}%fbox
}&%end subfloat
\subfloat[]{%
\begin{tabular}[b]{c|cccc}% === [b] added here ===
  & 0 & 1 & \dots & n\\\hline
a & & & &\b & & & &\c & & & &\\dots & & & &\d & & & &\\end{tabular}%
}%end subfloat
\end{tabular}%
\caption{Why resizebox shifts the baseline up?}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum 2013-01-04:**
As user adn has found out, the captions are still not perfectly aligned. (See comments below.) A possible solution would be switching to the `subcaption` package resp. its `\subcaptionbox` command:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}%
\subcaptionbox{}{%
\fbox{
\resizebox{0.5\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node {a};%
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%end resize
}%fbox
}&%end subcaptionbox
\subcaptionbox{}{%
\begin{tabular}{c|cccc}%
  & 0 & 1 & \dots & n\\\hline
a & & & &\b & & & &\c & & & &\\dots & & & &\d & & & &\\end{tabular}%
}%end \subcaptionbox
\end{tabular}%
\caption{Why resizebox shifts the baseline up?}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Please note that changing the baseline of the inner tabular (with `[b]`) is not necessary here since a `\subcaptionbox` always has its baseline between content and caption, and therefore the two `\subcaptionbox`es are already aligned by default.

Comment: Quick question, is it me or the table is a little bit shifted down in comparison to the `tikzpicture`?

Comment: Can't confirm that. Even if I use the magnifying lens of TeXworks the bottom rule of the picture is exactly on a horizontal line with the pixel at the bottom of the tabular.

Comment: I was talking about the captions (a) and (b), maybe it is just a visual effect.

Comment: Gosh, you are right! (No, it's not just a visual effect.)

Comment: When using my subcaption package instead of subfig (and replacing `\subfloat` with `\subcaptionbox`) the effect has gone. So I assume it's a bug in subfig!? Shall I add the subcaption code to my answer?

Comment: That would be good, to put the extra solution for (us) the picky ones :)

Comment: Ok, just did that.

Comment: Thanks for the extra effort. I would +1 again if I could... :)

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt: Would you consider offering a means to explicitly specify the baseline for a `\subcaptionbox`?

Comment: @krlmlr Since a `\subcaptionbox` has its baseline between content and caption they will be horizontally aligned this way automatically.